# ISOdate conversion issues

Tags: r, isodate

I am trying to convert dates with ISOdate function, but I face 2 issues:

- converting a date before 1970 gives an NA;
- converting a date after 1970 offsets by 1 month.

Here is the code I use:

```
firstDate <- as.Date("1910-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
todayDate <-  Sys.Date() #Lets say its 2021-09-04
firstDatePOSIX <- as.POSIXlt(firstDate)
todayDatePOSIX <- as.POSIXlt(todayDate)
firstDateISO <- ISOdate(firstDatePOSIX$year + 1900, firstDatePOSIX$mon, firstDatePOSIX$mday)
todayDateISO <- ISOdate(todayDatePOSIX$year + 1900, todayDatePOSIX$mon, todayDatePOSIX$mday)
```

`firstDateISO` returns NA

`todayDateISO` returns "2021-08-04 12:00:00 GMT" instead of "2021-09-04 12:00:00 GMT"

My questions:

- What to do to get `"1910-01-01 12:00:00 GMT"` with `firstDateISO`?
- What to do to get `"2021-09-04 12:00:00 GMT"` with `todayDateISO`?

Any help much appreciated.

---

System used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Big Sur version 11.5.1

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to use the `ISOdate` function here? You seem to already have `POSIXlt` dates. What are you trying to do with `ISOdate` function that you can't do with a `POSIXlt` date object? Note that the `$mon` value is from 0-11, not 1-12 as per the `?DateTimeClasses` help page. So you need to add 1 if you want the "normal" month value.

Comment: @MrFlick - Thank you for your comment. The aim of the exercise is to get the integer format of these dates (e.g., ```as.integer(firstDateISO)```) in order to insert them in a URL. @jay.sf's answer works absolutely marvellously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mon + 1`.

```
with(firstDatePOSIX, ISOdate(year + 1900, mon + 1, mday))
# [1] "1910-01-01 12:00:00 GMT"

with(todayDatePOSIX, ISOdate(year + 1900, mon + 1, mday))
# [1] "2021-09-04 12:00:00 GMT"
```